# npm5 does not accept proxy settings

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

**I upgraded to latest npm 5 today and it started throwing me following error.**

> ```
> npm ERR! code E407
> npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authorization Required: <node-module>
> ```

I have proxy setting configured in .npmrc file. Does NPM 5 maintain any other file for proxy setting?

Answer (score 2):

I too was facing the same issue but I believe my issue was due to NTLM authentication as I was on windows (sigh!).

If you too are on windows, follow these steps:

1. Install [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)
2. Open Fiddler -> Rules -> Automatically Authenticate
3. Change **proxy** and **https-proxy** of npm to "http://localhost:8888"

try running **npm install** now.

Note: You may need to change proxy settings of Git too.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by deleting npm folder from AppData/
And then ran

```
npm cache clean
```

and reinstalled npm using

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

Comment: That worked for me. The npm folder was under AppData/Roaming/

Comment: Actually they applied patch to 5.0 version of npm immediately, so now latest npm is 5.0.1, which fixed that issue.